# Random sphere-valued fields

Tags: statistics, random-variables, homotopy-theory

I would like to generate random functions from an $m$-sphere $S^m$ to an $n$-sphere $S^n$ that are not too wild, some kind of generalization of [random Gaussian fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_random_field).

More precisely, I want $f(x)$, for any $x\in S^m$, to be a random point on $S^n$ with uniform probability distribution, and a property that $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ are probably close to each other, whenever $x$ and $y$ are close. (The analogy in Gaussian processes is that the covariance decays via some given function)

One question I have in mind is to see, how often a random function is homotopically trivial.

Is there a way to define such maps algorithmically and/or a reference to a rigorous definition of such sphere-valued fields?

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe it would be more suitable on mathoverflow.. any feedback?

Comment: I'm not sure what the point of such an investigation would be. Consider just the case $m=n$. Suppose you write a random variable that generates the identity mapping with probability $1/42$, and wraps the sphere one time around itself with probability $1 - 1/42$. Then you "investigate" how often the mapping is homotopically trivial. You get just the number $1/42$ back. What does it tell you except that the author of the random variable liked the number $42$? What's the point in investigating an artificially constructed random variable?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin My question is whether it can be define in some "natural" way. For scalar funtions, the Gaussian process, defined only by a covariance function, is the analogy. It is a soft question. The motivation behing is this: I'm analazying zero sets of functions $\Bbb R^m\to \Bbb R^n$ and want to see, in case when the zero set is "isolated" inside a boundary sphere $S^{m-1}$, how often the zero set can be detected by non-extendability of the boundary map $S^{m-1}\to S^{n-1}$ to all of $B^m$...